Laravel 11, como puedo ejecutar comandos artisan en mi paquete custom de laravel sin tener artisan instalado en mi paquete
tengo un paquete de laravel que estoy desarrollando. Para ir probando que va OK el paquete me he creado un proyecto de prueba de laravel para pruebas y dentro de un directorio packages estoy desarrollandolo, hasta aqui sin problemas.
Los problemas me vienen cuando quiero desarrollar una serie de tests  y necesito ejecutar comandos artisan en el. Para ello iba a usar el comando :_
Artisan::call('comando')

Pero claro, mi paquete no tiene instalado artisan, aunque se este ejecutando desde un proyecto, el paquete por si mismo no tiene en su vendor (ni deberia de tenerlo) el binario de artisan, ya que eso depende mas del entorno en el que esta, como el proyecto de pruebas donde lo estoy desarrollando.
Mi test es :
<?php

namespace josanangel\tests;

use Faker\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class RepositoryTest extends TestCase
{


    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    /**
     * A basic test example.
     */
    public function test_command_creates_single_repository_successfully(): void
    {
        $factory = Factory::create();
       $repositoryName =  $factory->word();


        Artisan::call("make:repository ",['name'=>$repositoryName]);
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}

El test esta incompleto, pero ahora intento buscar la manera de que peuda ejecutar comandos artisan. Al ejecutar ese test me da el siguiente error :
Error: Class "Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan" not found

Porque no debe de encontrar en su vendor particular nada asociado a ese comando.
No se muy bien cual es, entonces, el protocolo a seguir cuando quieras tener tests en tu paquete y tengas que ejecutar en el comandos artisan, por ejemplo.

Lo que tienes que hacer es un test de la clase command que hayas hecho, no de la ejecución de artisan (eso ya está testeado). Indica cual es la clase que responde a "make:repository" para ver como podemos ayudarte con ese test.

Sé que no es la solución perfecta, pero https://laravel-zero.com/ es un paquete minimalista que te instala una app que para todos los efectos reemplaza la línea de comando de laravel

Gracias, ya encontre una solucion, lo he puesto en la pregunta por si a alguien mas le sirve en un futuro

Buscando por internet me topé con un paquete de laravel que simula 'virtualmente' las acciones de artisan, es decir, las ejecutas pero no son persistentes, el paquete es :
"orchestra/testbench": "^9.8"

Y tiene estas dependencias para que funcione:
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^11.5",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.24",
    "orchestra/testbench": "^9.8"
}

En los tests se puede usar de esta manera :
 $this->artisan("artisan optimize")->assertOk();

Importandolo con esta linea :
use Orchestra\Testbench\TestCase

